# How to show Qt (widgets) app on QNX based on specific location and size?

Tags: qt, window, qnx

I'm trying to make my Qt widgets-based app to run on QNX device on a specific location and size using `QWidget::setGeometry(..)`, but it always get shown in full screen.

The app uses `QMainWindow` with menu bar and a `QGLWidget` as the central widget.

The same code running on Linux desktop works fine, positioned based on the provided `x` & `y` and with the provided size.

Does the windowing system on QNX not support this? Or is it Qt that does not able to use the windowing system on QNX? Or something else? I don't get it :(

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt platform plugin is implemented with the platform capabilities and limitations in mind. Seems like QNX only supports window switching, no full fledged window management as you would have in windows or linux, therefore Qt applications are implicitly, and possibly intrinsically full screen.

If you desire to not have it on the entire screen, just implement a blank main window and position the central widget by having it free floating rather than being put in a layout inside the main window.

But that doesn't mean you will be able to put more applications on the screen, you will only not be using the entire screen for the one application window it displays. You could fake multiple applications by simply using multiple widgets and implement your own fake window manager, the caveat is you will still be using one process, which may or may not end up being an issue.

Here is what I mean by a "free floating widget":

```
class YourWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    YourWidget(QWidget * p) : QWidget(p) { resize(100, 100); }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.fillRect(rect(), Qt::black);
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        resize(500, 500);
        QWidget * blank = new QWidget;
        setCentralWidget(blank);
        widget = new YourWidget(blank);
        widget->move(rect().center());
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e) {
        widget->move(e->pos());
    }
private:
    YourWidget * widget;
};
```

`YourWidget` is no longer anchored by a layout, it is free to move to arbitrary position, it is still drawn in the confines of its container widget, which is just a blank widget set as the window's central widget and lifetime is also managed automatically.

Comment: Hi ddriver, thanks for the answer. What do you mean exactly by "having it free floating"? At this moment I set the QGLWidget as the central widget using QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(..).

Comment: Thanks for the new hint. I tried as you suggested, with the difference being the YourWidget is another QMainWindow which contains both menu bar and QGLWidget (as central). Unfortunately the YourWidget still takes the full screen somehow :(

Comment: You should not have a main window inside a main window, there is only one main window. Don't use a main window if you want to have control over the size and position on QNX.

Comment: I see... indeed if I only have one main window and the supposedly central widget is not set as the central but just "floating" then I can control the size and position. But how do I position a whole main window including its menu bar then? Is it actually possible?

Comment: The main window implementation seems to be tied to the platform plugin implementation - you can't use it. You can however implement a widget with a menu, basically implement a custom widget with the functionality from `QMainWIndow` you need. It might be a viable option to implement a `QMainWindow` derived class which is not tied to the platform plugin, if overriding that behavior was indeed included in the design. Look through the implementation of `QMainWindow` to determine whether this is possible.

Comment: That sucks. Ok I'll think about it. Another option that I know would work is to use QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene, to have the GL drawn as the background and the UI controls added to the scene. The positioning then can be done by setting the widgets' position via its proxy widgets. Anyhow, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I'd recommend going for QML instead - it has better graphics performance and is MUCH easier and faster to implement UI with it.